# How to programmatically correct the landscape to portrait error for fragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have created the following app whereby it makes use of fragments. I have come to notice that whenever, I tilt the screen from portrait to landscape or vice versa, the app will crash with the following quote

> Unfortunately, (AppName) has stopped

I have researched and understood that this error is shown due to process with the fragment life cycle, whereby the fragment view is unable to re-create a new fragment view when the previous fragment view has been destroyed. Hence, I would like to know how could I programmatically override this error such that when I tilt the screen, the app wouldn't crash

ERROR LOG:

```
11-21 14:44:46.743: E/AndroidRuntime(25374): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-21 14:44:46.743: E/AndroidRuntime(25374): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-21 14:44:46.743: E/AndroidRuntime(25374):    at com.dapoaugury.channelappdemo.fragment.ChannelAppProductFragment$LoadViewTask.loadListing(ChannelAppProductFragment.java:106)
11-21 14:44:46.743: E/AndroidRuntime(25374):    at com.dapoaugury.channelappdemo.fragment.ChannelAppProductFragment$LoadViewTask.onPostExecute(ChannelAppProductFragment.java:96)
11-21 14:44:46.743: E/AndroidRuntime(25374):    at com.dapoaugury.channelappdemo.fragment.ChannelAppProductFragment$LoadViewTask.onPostExecute(ChannelAppProductFragment.java:1)
11-21 14:44:46.743: E/AndroidRuntime(25374):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
11-21 14:44:46.743: E/AndroidRuntime(25374):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
11-21 14:44:46.743: E/AndroidRuntime(25374):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
11-21 14:44:46.743: E/AndroidRuntime(25374):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-21 14:44:46.743: E/AndroidRuntime(25374):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-21 14:44:46.743: E/AndroidRuntime(25374):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
11-21 14:44:46.743: E/AndroidRuntime(25374):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 14:44:46.743: E/AndroidRuntime(25374):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-21 14:44:46.743: E/AndroidRuntime(25374):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-21 14:44:46.743: E/AndroidRuntime(25374):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-21 14:44:46.743: E/AndroidRuntime(25374):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code:

```
private void loadListing() {
        ChannelAppProductsArrayAdapter adapter = new ChannelAppProductsArrayAdapter(
                mContex, R.layout.itemlisting, productList, imageLoader);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //EDITED VERSION TO INITIATE SLIDER DRAWER
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        //END OF EDITED VERSION TO INITIATE SLIDER DRAWER


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                /*String text = "Item click... should be implemented @ position: "
                        + position;
                Toast.makeText(mContex, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                Product product = productList.get(position);
                String productID = product.getId();


                String productDesc = product.getName();
                TextView ProductSummary;
                String productName=product.getDescription();
                TextView ProductName;
                ImageView productImage;

                //EDITED VERSION TO SHOW RIGHT DRAWER-18/11/2014

                mDrawerToggle = new CustomActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawer);
                mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
                mDrawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

                //To lock the drawer from being manually toggled
                //mDrawer.setDrawerLockMode(1,GravityCompat.END);
                Log.i("View onItemClick: ArtistProductDetailsFragment", "toggleRightDrawer()"+ productDesc);
                //END OF EDITED VERSION TO SHOW RIGHT DRAWER-18/11/2014

                //EDITED VERSION TO DISPLAY VIEW FOR SELECTED FRAGMENT ITEM-19/11/2014
                View RDrawerView = mDrawer.findViewById(R.id.preview_layout);

                //To set TextView of Product Name
                ProductSummary = (TextView) RDrawerView.findViewById(R.id.productsummary);
                ProductSummary.setText(productDesc);

                //To set TextView of product description
                ProductName= (TextView) RDrawerView.findViewById(R.id.productdesc);
                ProductName.setText(productName);

                //To get product Image from array
                productImage =(ImageView) RDrawerView.findViewById(R.id.productimage);
                String imgFilePath = url + imagename;
                imageLoader.displayImage(imgFilePath, productImage, options);
                //END OF EDITED VERSION TO DISPLAY VIEW FOR SELECTED FRAGMENT ITEM-19/11/2014

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you attach crash log

Comment: @GKTHEBOSS I have updated the crash log

Comment: if the app is simple to upload the send a source code by mail .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Asynctask in Fragment is probably problem in onpostexecute part. Try this below. May be help.

```
@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

     if (getActivity()!=null) {      
         loadListing();
        }

 }

private void loadListing() {
    ChannelAppProductsArrayAdapter adapter = new ChannelAppProductsArrayAdapter(
            mContex, R.layout.itemlisting, productList, imageLoader);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

 }
```

Comment: Thanks!I will try it out and update you on the progress

Comment: I have got this as part of my "{onPostExecute)" code: @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   progressDialog.dismiss();
   loadListing();
   
  }    how do i integrate your solution into the above code?

Comment: Send your loadListing(). There is NPE and there test getActivity()!=null.

Comment: I don't quite get your meaning

Comment: Send your part code loadListing(). I must see your code to help integrate my solution.

Comment: Try change your onPostExecute like above

Comment: listView.setOnItemClickListener from lodListing() give to onActivityCreated method of Fragment after calling Asynctask.

Comment: It worked!thanks! could you help to upvote the question pls.thanks